# Time series forecast using SVM?

Tags: python, predictive-modeling, time-series, svm

I have a pandas data frame like this:

```
(index) 0           sie

0       1997-01-01  11.2
1        1997-01-03  12.3
2        1997-01-04  11.5
...
12454    2017-02-01  13.2
```

I would like to use SVM to predict the future values of the `sie`. How can I implement python code to predict these values?

I am doing something like this:

`model = svm.SVR().fit(df[0],df['sie'])`

But it is giving me this error:

`ValueError: Found input variables with inconsistent numbers of samples: [1, 12455]`

Although both `df[0]`and`df['sie']` have same shape of `(12455,)`

**Note**: *I don't have continuous data (some dates, in between, are missing), also values in `0` are `datetime.date()` objects.*

Comment: Try this `model = svm.SVR().fit(df['0'],df['sie'])`

Comment: Giving `KeyError: '0'`. I don't think this is a problem though..

Comment: I used `df.rename(columns={0:'Dates'}, inplace=True)` and `model = svm.SVR().fit(df['Dates'],df['sie'])` still giving me  `**ValueError**`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here, a very good article: http://machinelearningmastery.com/time-series-forecasting-supervised-learning/

In a few words, define a window of size n and that is the size of your feature vector. Reshape the dataset and play.

Comment: Actually I did not used sliding window method and trained my model. That was a disastrous mistake. The model trained well for the training time with X as the time feature :-P  but predicted kinda average value for future times. Sliding window actually converts the time series into a supervised learning problem. \Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I used to solve the value error:
`model = svm.SVR().fit(np.transpose(np.matrix(df['Dates'])),np.transpose(np.matrix(df['sie'])))`

More Info: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30813044/sklearn-found-arrays-with-inconsistent-numbers-of-samples-when-calling-linearre