# Time series regression using SVR

Tags: python, regression, training

I have time series data stored in a data frame as follows:

```
Time, c1, c2, c3 

0, 0.55, 0.4 , 0.3 

1, 0.8 , 0.1 , 0.6 

2,  0.9 , 0.5 , 0.7

....
```

And I want to predict the values of c1, c2, c3 at the next time interval. How can I implement a python code to predict values using SVR (Given above structure)?

Comment: Mayber refer to [this](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/questions/19707/time-series-forecast-using-svm) answer.

Comment: Thanks, I have checked this but my case is different as it's multivariate time series, In the post, you referring to, one value is predicted which is different in my case ... Any further help is appreciated

Comment: Have you tried [this](https://www.analyticsvidhya.com/blog/2018/09/multivariate-time-series-guide-forecasting-modeling-python-codes/) guide. It uses VAR instead of SVR. Also consider reshaping your data so that ith row contain k previous rows and use 3 SVRs - for each predicted value respectively.

Comment: @GrozaiL I just would like to make sure if my understanding is correct when you said use 3 SVRs for each predicted value ... Do you mean to reshape the data such that I consider each output independently from each other and fit a model for each predicted value

Comment: To make it more clear ==> This mean I will take for example last 10 values of c1 and put them in a row and these 10 values will be feature vector to predict the 11th value of c1 (target) using the first SVR model ... and do the same for the other outputs .. Right?